# Is there a way to restart node server in runtime?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, hapi.js

I am trying to define an endpoint in my express server that whenever this end point is called, the server restarts automatically in runtime.
for example, using express my server would look something like this ...

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express();

app.post('/restart', (req,res)=>{
//restart or create a new instance of the server

// then reply
res.json({
    'message': 'server restarted successfully'
   })
})

// =======================
// start the server ======
// =======================
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000; 

app.listen(port);
console.log('server running at  http://localhost:' + port);
```

*NOTE*: Although I am using expressJS, I am open to other solutions like HAPI for example.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into [cluster](https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html). Start a new worker whenever one closes. Then simply exit whenever needed.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I know of how to restart a node instance is in the CLI level via npm forever or the pm2, but this is for deployment level xP.

Answer (score 0):

You would need npm module `forever` to be globally installed on your system and `Shelljs` as a dependency. Initially start your server as `forever start {Path to server.js}`. Then you can do

```
var express = require('express')
var shell = require('shelljs')
var app = express();

app.post('/restart', (req,res)=>{
//restart or create a new instance of the server
shell.exec('forever restart {Path to server.js}');

// then reply
res.json({
    'message': 'server restarted successfully'
   })
})

// =======================
// start the server ======
// =======================
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000; 

app.listen(port);
console.log('server running at  http://localhost:' + port);
```

Also see that you will not get a response as the server would have restarted. You would just get a refused to connect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) to start, stop your server using simple commands.

Starting an application in production mode is as easy as:

```
pm2 start app.js
```

Stop all apps

```
pm2 stop all
```

Restart all apps

```
pm2 restart all
```

I hope this will work for you.

HTH Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since express uses the HTTP from Node, you might initialize the Express server by yourself with the Node HTTP functions, noted [here](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#app.listen).

Once you have the server started, you might close it and restart it as you wish, as mentioned [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_close_callback).

Just you have to be careful with the already opened connections, as calling the HTTP instance for close will leave the already opened connection(s) still open. More information about closing them all; can be found [here](https://dev.to/gajus/how-to-terminate-a-http-server-in-node-js-ofk).